# Rails Popup alert with form for a variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, alert, popupwindow

I have a link in my rails website that needs one line of information from the user. How do I set this up.

click link > go to method in controller > show modal alert > user types one line > this value is set to a variable in the method and the method continues as planned.

How do I send an alert that changes the value of a local variable?